# Estimator's Efficiency vs. Consistency

Tags: inference, estimators, efficiency

I know the definition of both (I think), but they seem so equal at the same time. Any clarification?

I know that as the sample size goes to infinity; the estimator converges to the population parameter (becomes more consistent). The efficiency however, is at any given point; the relative probability of one estimator being closer to the population parameter than another estimator. I.e. a comparative concept.

So is consistency more about the variance? I.e. a slimmer distribution? And the efficiency does not necessarily increase with a smaller variance, due to bias?

Comment: note: not all estimators are consistent.

Comment: Makes sense, but I still find the distinction hazy.

Comment: talking about consistency is when we have one estimator. But then say you have two consistent estimators, then which do you choose? - here typically you need to turn to efficienty "measures".

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(statistics)

Comment: Ahh of course! Thank you! Yes trust me, I read those two plenty, must have missed the "more than one" distinction.